# Can I create a self-contained, cross-platform Electron application?

Tags: electron

I'm considering creating an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) application. Ideally this application is distributed as a single file that runs on multiple operating systems.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: As a single file, it's not possible at the moment. Electron can be setup to create distributions for different operating systems, though.

Comment: It's not possible at the moment or in the future, in Electron or any other system.